# TypeScript - How to require an object where one key has a specified type?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to define the following function:

```
getStringValidation<FormValues>("name")
```

and have the following constraints:

1. `FormValues` is an object that contains the `"name"` key (or whatever the argument is)
2. The value that corresponds to this key in the object should be of type `string`.

For example:

**Allowed**

```
getStringValidation<{ name: string, age: number }>("name")
```

**Should error**

```
getStringValidation<{ name: string, age: number }>("age") // the value is of type number

getStringValidation<{ name: string, age: number }>("address") // the key doesn't exist in the object
```

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you define a type:

```
type KeysOfType<O, T> = {
    [K in keyof O]: O[K] extends T ? K : never;
}[keyof O];
```

to extract the keys of `O` that have values of type `T`, then defining your function is straightforward:

```
function getStringValidation<T>(propName: KeysOfType<T, string>) {
    throw Error("not implemented")
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=2&pln=12&pc=1#code/OYUwLgymBOCWB2wBqBDANrAJissD28APAN4AE8KAtiAFykDOMCwANKSqHfAK6UBGIaKQC+APgAUAIgrVJASgBQS0JCaJUGbLgIlyVWgzWt2ncrwFCxUjiHmkA9PdJgAFiFIA3dN3ex6pPAAzZwBPAAd3Hn5BZXAoOHV0LBx8IjIZA0YE4xsuc0ERCUkUTExoEHp6O0dnN1IAaxAQ0kw8CvgAcjBSEAAPP26EWvc8PgArEABjMCU+sLxobrBw9wBpJvoAeUCAFRXCTbYd0VIAXlJiBVJr0gBtVdIhxpCg0k2AXTpN+-ee3rAQPBMP4dqQAPykB5cEAeQQAbgUwluz1eHwRCkC3Hg01SpBU8WYGmS2iIx3EYWgeDCADl9HR1iEtrt9js2FlmKI5BcrjdXJSAO6kACi0Ep0Ck8Dwg0oYTQIGo8ABmHkiKAA)